# Equivalence classes of the similarity relation on complex 2x2 matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, jordan-normal-form, similar-matrices

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field. Two matrices $A,B \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n} $ are said to be similar if there exists an invertible matrix $S \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$ such that $A = S^{-1}BS$. It can be shown the this relation is an equivalence relation.

**My question is:** How many equivalence classes of the similarity relation on the set of complex 2x2 matrices, $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, are there? And which ones are they?

My idea would be to use the fact that matrices are similar if and only if they have the same Jordan normal form (up to a permutation of the Jordan blocks). Or is there any another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, a similarity class of a matrix $A \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$ is given by its [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form), up to a permutation of the Jordan blocks.

As the cardinality of the Jordan normal blocks is the one of the [continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum) $\mathfrak c$ (i.e. the one of $\mathbb C$), the cardinality you're looking for is $\mathfrak c$.

Comment: So the equivalence classes have representatives of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a&0\\0&a \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} a&1\\0&a \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} a&0\\0&b \end{pmatrix}$ or $\begin{pmatrix} a&1\\0&b \end{pmatrix}$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ and $Re(a) > Re(b)$, $Im(a) > Im(b)$. Would that be correct?

Comment: @Apollo13 No: the fourth is not a Jordan form. Also the first can be included in the third by allowing $a=b$

Comment: Not exactly. If $a \neq b$, $\begin{pmatrix} a&0\\0&b \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} a&1\\0&b \end{pmatrix}$ are similar matrices. As @Apollo13 mentioned, $\begin{pmatrix} a&1\\0&b \end{pmatrix}$ is not a Jordan form. Also, it is not necessary to introduce real and imaginary parts. Why do you do so?

Comment: Ah, yes of course, thank you! I introduced the real and imaginary part because similar matrices have the same Jordan form up to a permutation of the order of the blocks. Hence, $\begin{pmatrix} a&0\\0&b \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} b&0\\0&a \end{pmatrix}$ belong to the same equivalence class. In other words, the set of matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a&0\\0&b \end{pmatrix}$ does not map one-to-one onto the set of the equivalence classes of its members.

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that make sense. However you can just suppose that you take an order on $\mathbb C$ like the [lexicographic one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20lexicographic%20or,of%20a%20totally%20ordered%20set.). Not sure that describing it is adding much value.

Comment: Yes, it probably doesn't. Anyway, thinking about it, I realize that I should have written $Re(a)\geq Re(b)$ and $Im(a) \neq Im(b)$ as a condition.